# Compatibility problem on some libraries when installing pods on React Native macOS

Tags: macos, react-native, cocoapods

I have a React Native macOS project and I need some libraries to be installed to my project but I'm constantly getting compatibility errors on `pod install.` I've been Googling for hours and couldn't find anything. I tried alternative libraries but I got the same error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**The Errors**

```
[!] The platform of the target `RNMacOS5-macOS` (macOS 10.14) is not compatible with `RNScreens (2.9.0)`, which does not support `macOS`.

[!] The platform of the target `RNMacOS5-macOS` (macOS 10.14) is not compatible with `RNCMaskedView (0.1.10)`, which does not support `macOS`.

[!] The platform of the target `RNMacOS5-macOS` (macOS 10.14) is not compatible with `RNGestureHandler (1.6.1)`, which does not support `macOS`.

[!] The platform of the target `RNMacOS5-macOS` (macOS 10.14) is not compatible with `react-native-safe-area-context (3.0.7)`, which does not support `macOS`.
```

**Here are my dependencies on my project:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-devtools": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-anchor-point": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-draggable-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-expandable-section-list": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-macos": "^0.61.0-0",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.30.1",
    "react-native-nested-listview": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-responsive-grid": "^0.41.993",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-sortable-grid": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0"
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like support for react native macOS is limited, I would say you have to create your own custom navigation screens. I got around everything by using Modals. Its bad practise but ti solved my a lot of problems.

Comment: My problem was to navigate between the screens or open a modal and I was needed to these libraries. But I used react-navigation v2.x version (pulled from Github) and it worked perfectly. It's deprecated but it works... Thank you for your comment.

Comment: No thank you... as i will be using react navigation v2!